# Is simultaneous use of GitHub SSH Keys and GitHub token creating conflict?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, pycharm, virtual-machine

I have created SSH keys for my GitHub account, prior to being assigned as collaborator to a  team project. The team insited to create GitHub token to conform with the project work from start, and I blindly followed their instructions creating a Git token.Then, when trying to clone  the project repo into my PyCharm( community version) located on a Linux based Virtual machine, the PyCharm completely crashed and I can not recover it Is it possible  the simultanoeus use of SSH keys and Github token to create conflict? If that is the case, how can undo the simultaneous presence of these two? Which one of these two protections is less harmful to be "killed" and how to do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general, assuming the site supports both HTTPS and SSH, as GitHub does, it's fine to use both HTTPS with a token and SSH with an SSH key.  Note, however, that for GitHub, HTTPS requires a token and SSH requires an SSH key, and there's no way to interchange them or use them both at the same time.  Thus, which authentication method you use depends on which protocol you use to clone, fetch, or push.  That, in turn, can be selected based on personal preference or on other considerations (e.g., whether a corporate environment requires HTTPS or whether SSH is more reliable in a circumstance due to avoiding proxies).

If you're at the terminal, you can run `git remote -v` in the repository to see what remotes are available, and if the URL starts with `https://`, then it's HTTPS, and since GitHub uses `git` as the SSH username, if it starts with `ssh://` or `git@`, then it's an SSH remote.

In no event should either of these cause an editor or IDE to crash.  If your editor or IDE has crashed, that's definitely a bug in that software.  To debug, I might recommend running it from the command line to see if it reports any relevant problems or debug information, and then either take appropriate action to fix the problem or report the bug to the author or distributor of PyCharm.  Sometimes there are additional debugging arguments that can be used to get helpful information as well; see the documentation for your editor for more details.

If the bug appears to be in the actual cloning functionality of PyCharm, then simply clone the repository from the command line using `git clone URL`, and then switch into the repository and invoke your editor.  You can disable the Git integration in your editor if necessary and use the command line if the Git integration is faulty or buggy.